# Working of document listener for particular file in jtabbedpane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, jinternalframe, documentlistener

Loading two files in textarea by using JtabbedPane. Modify the text in file1 using documentlistener and no modifications on file2 But when close the jinternalframe for the file2, it asks modify the data save or not dialog box and file1 normally closed. My problem how to dialog open for modify the file itself(i.e file1).

Here is my code,

```
public class Open extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JTextArea tx;
ArrayList<String> fileList;
File file;
String filename=null;
int i=0;
boolean update =false;
 public Open() {

   fileList=new ArrayList<String>();
initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    Open.setText("Open");
    Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            OpenActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(Open);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    final JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal=  jc.showOpenDialog(Open.this);
    String title;
    String s=null;
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)     
    file = jc.getSelectedFile();
    if (jc.getSelectedFile()!= null) {
       BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuffer str1 = new StringBuffer("");
        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder sbHex = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
        final StringBuilder pb = new StringBuilder();
        int bytesCounter =0;        
        String helloWorldInHex=null;
        int value=0;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            try {

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        String t = str.toString();
       filename=file.getPath();
       final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("",true,true); 
      final String filePath=file.getAbsolutePath();
      i++;
      internalFrame.setName("Doc "+i);
       tx=new JTextArea();
         internalFrame.setTitle(filename);
        try {
            internalFrame.setSelected(true);
        } 
        catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }           
        tp.add(internalFrame);
        try{
            tp.setSelectedIndex(i-1);  
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ioe){   
        }
        tx.setText(t);
        internalFrame.add(tx);
      internalFrame.setVisible(true);

      Document doc=tx.getDocument();
      doc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
           @Override
           public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            update =true;
           }

           @Override
           public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
               update =true;
           }

           @Override
           public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
               update =true;
           }
       });
        internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {


                String name=tx.getName();

     if(update==true){

          update=false;
        int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                          "Save Changes to this Document", "Quit", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
           int chooserStatus;
        if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
          boolean success;
                String editorString;
                FileWriter fwriter;
                PrintWriter outputFile;
                try {
                    DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
                    String line = tx.getText();
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(line));
                    while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                        d.writeBytes(line + "\r\n");
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException ee) {       
                    success = false;
                }
         success = true;
                i--;
               tp.remove(internalFrame);
           }
        else if(reply==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
        {
            i--;
      tp.remove(internalFrame);
       }
      }
     else 
     {
          i--;
    tp.remove(internalFrame);
     }

            }
        });   

}

}                                    
public static void main(String args[]) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                           UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Open.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            new Open().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
   }
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Open;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have just one `boolean update` flag but I would suggest to have separate one for each file state. Thus you track each file changes independently. You can organize a map of states if you have multiple files.

Comment: how to seperate one for each file?

Comment: E.g. by Map<String,Boolean> the key should file name and value is the state.

Comment: i have one doubt, what i write into if condition. if(..) only executes when document modified.

Comment: I don't understand the comment

Comment: aboue my code when document modified some code executed and without modify some code excuted. please see aboue code if(update==true)...